# Distribution of ratio of dependent gamma-disributed variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Let $ X = X_1, ..., X_n $ i.i.d random variables with $U_{[0, 1]}$ distribution. I need to prove that $X_{(k)} \sim \xi = \frac{\xi_1 + ... + \xi_{k - 1}}{\xi_1 + ... + \xi_{n+1}}$, where $\xi_i$ are independent with $Exp(1)$ distribution.

It's well known that $U_{(k)} \sim Beta(k, n + 1 - k)$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \xi_i \sim \Gamma(n, 1)$ and its also easy to find distribution of ratio of independent Gamma distributions, however in our case Gamma distributions are dependent, and my question is how can we find distribution of $\xi$?

Comment: You can say $\xi=\frac{U}{U+V}$ where $U$ and $V$ are independent Gamma variates.

Comment: what is $X_{(k)}$? Ordered statistics?

Comment: @StubbornAtom thats clever idea, thanks

Comment: @Mahdi yes, ordered statistic